# Find the related group

Tags: r

I have data like this:

```
num group
0     433
0     433
0     433
0     211
0     211
0     211
1     309
1     309
1     309
0     424
0     947
1     309
0     433
```

I would like to check if a specific group has always 0 or 1 value in num column but my data frame has many rows (i.e. group 433 is at the start and it is possible to be in other rows in df). How is it possible to index it?

Comment: However simplistic, this is a code writing request

Comment: Have you tried  `table(df1$group, df2$num)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using data.table to check if the `length` of `unique` elements in 'num' column is only 1 after grouping by 'group'.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'group', `if` the `length` of `unique` elements in 'num' is 1, then we get the Subset of data.table (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(uniqueN(num) == 1) .SD, by = group]
```

NOTE: In the example provided by the OP, all the 'group' have only single unique element, so it will get the full dataset.

If we need the 'group' ids for having only a single `unique` element

```
setDT(df1)[, if(uniqueN(num) == 1)  group, by = group]$V1
#[1] 433 211 309 424 947
```

---

If we need the 'num' column along with 'group' whenever there is only a single `unique` 'num' per 'group'

```
setDT(df1)[,if(uniqueN(num)==1) .(num = num[1L]) , by = group]
#   group num
#1:   433   0
#2:   211   0
#3:   309   1
#4:   424   0
#5:   947   0
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfect. Just some clarifications. I can make the same for 0 group changing the 1 value?

Comment: @Jake It is checking whether the value in 'num' is only of a particular type for each 'group', so it will work even if it is 1, 0, or any other value

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to keep in this line of your code also the value (0,1) of every group `setDT(df1)[, if(uniqueN(num) == 1)  group, by = group]$V1`
?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `table`?

```
table(df)
   group
num 211 309 424 433 947
  0   3   0   1   4   1
  1   0   4   0   0   0
```

**Update**

Here are some `dplyr` alternatives:

```
library(dplyr)

# To find the number of distinct values per group
df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(n_distinct(num))

# To find groups that have only one distinct value and their corresponding value
df %>% group_by(group) %>% 
    summarise(UniqueNum = ifelse(n_distinct(num) > 1, NA, unique(num))) %>% 
    na.omit()

# To find all distinct values per group
df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(list(unique(num))) %>% tidyr::unnest()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see how many different values each group has with `tapply` in base R

```
with(dd, tapply(num, group, function(x) length(unique(x))))
```

No re-indexing required.

Answer (score 1):

Well, something similar to @Mr.Flick's approach.

You can use `aggregate` to find out `unique` values for each group

```
aggregate(num ~ group, df, unique)

# group  num
#1   211    0
#2   309    1
#3   424    0
#4   433    0
#5   947    0
```

If you want only those groups which has only one value everytime, you can extend this to

```
a <- aggregate(num ~ group, df, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1)
a[a$num,1]
#[1] 211 309 424 433 947
```

Comment: @akrun please stop this. I have not downvoted your answer.

Comment: @akrun I don't know why would someone downvote your answer and why is my answer downvoted?

Comment: it is. Please check.

Comment: same thing happened for me.  But if I give an objective evaluation of your post, the `unique` will give the unique values and the OP is asking (which I believe) for identifying group that have only a single 'num'.  So your post may not be the one OP wanted.

Comment: Possible. But this is what everyone else wrote. Anyways, updated the post.

Comment: Mr. Flick's answer gives length of unique elements.